# Microsoft account photo using Graph API without Authentication Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to access Microsoft account's profile photo without an Authentication Token? Coming from Live SDK and migrating to Graph API.

Simply pointing to this Uri doesn't provide the user's profile picture: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/[id]/photo/$value`

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
    "request-id": "828a9865-e0d6-4af2-8895-da09f3fa1402",
    "date": "2018-09-29T08:43:57"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Graph API without Authentication Token. But you can call some data  not on behalf of a user by OAuth client credentials grant flow:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service